# Try to setup the autoresizingMask of a View doesn't work in Xcode 7.1.1 like in other examples

Tags: ios, swift

a lot of examples setup a view autoresizingMask with this code

```
scrollView?.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable
```

In Xcode 7.1.1 I get an error:

> : Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two
>   'NSAutoresizingMaskOptions' operands

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me:

```
    scrollView?.autoresizingMask.insert(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable)
    scrollView?.autoresizingMask.insert(NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable)
    print(scrollView?.autoresizingMask)
```

with is 18 = (2 + 16)

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2:

```
view.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions([.ViewWidthSizable,.ViewMaxXMargin,.ViewMinYMargin,.ViewHeightSizable,.ViewMaxYMargin])
```

Swift 3:

```
view.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions([.viewWidthSizable,.viewMaxXMargin,.viewMinYMargin,.viewHeightSizable,.viewMaxYMargin])
```